# Turn on auto-correct when using a Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: nexus-7, auto-correct, external-keyboard

I have been using my Nexus 7 for schoolwork and I love it. One problem, however, is that when I connect to my Bluetooth keyboard I no longer get auto-correct suggestions. I then decided to install Swiftkey 3 and discovered that if I had SwiftKey set as the default I could see a prediction bar, but there was still no auto-correct/auto-completion.

How can I have auto-correct enabled when a hardware keyboard is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it has been reported as a [SwiftKey bug](http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116697-4-swiftkey-tablet-bugs-/suggestions/3492928-when-using-a-physical-keyboard-swiftkey-tablet-do) for the Nexus 10 as well.

Your best best is probably wait to get this fixed. I suggest you click the Vote button in their support site to increase the bug's priority. I just added 3 votes for you!

*NOTE: I don't use SwiftKey. I use GO Keyboard.*

Comment: I guess I'll just have to wait. I just tried Go Keyboard but it doesn't support shift/ctrl/caps on a physical properly.